Does remote config for web projects still have throttling?
I want to use remote config for my react project but my configs are not suitable for long time caching when we want to edit them. For instance, I will send my requests to our backend by using a remote config parameter. When BE updates this parameter I need to update it in remote config paralelly. Is is possible to invalidate caching and fetching parameters in real time?
When I read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=web#throttling, it says :
If an app fetches too many times in a short time period, fetch calls may be throttled. In such cases, the SDK throws a FETCH_THROTTLE error. The default and recommended production fetch interval for Remote Config is 12 hours, which means that configs won't be fetched from the backend more than once in a 12 hour window, regardless of how many fetch calls are actually made.
When I apply settings.minimumFetchIntervalMillis to 300 ms in development, it is working without any problem and when I change a parameter value it is reflecting to ui by refreshing the page immediately. I am curious about production behaviour with many users
